# Latent Class Analysis Model Selection

Tags: statistics

When conducting Latent Class Analysis sometimes the information criterion (i.e., AIC,  BIC, aBIC) don't select the same model. Such is the case in a study of substance use patterns that I am conducting among 774 men who have sex with men. Figure [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/23zmT.png) shows the fit criterion plotted for each number of latent classes. BIC and CAIC select the three class model (See Figure [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yEyCO.png)). However, the aBIC selects a five class model (See Figure 2).

How do you select a model solution under these circumstances? Is there a way to select variables or collapse variables down in order to optimize results?

Answer (score 4):

It is never easy to select the number of classes for LCA, but there are some rules of thumb that I follow:

1. Based on [Nylund, Asparouhov & Muthén (2007)](https://www.statmodel.com/download/LCA_tech11_nylund_v83.pdf) you want to follow BIC and bootstrap likelihood ratio test (BLRT). Even then, they seldom agree – BLRT will tell you to pick a model with more classes, BIC will be more conservative and suggest fewer classes. But this is as close as you can get by using statistical tests.
2. Rely on the available theory underlying your model. Look for potential discrepancies with your theoretical knowledge and try to deduce from the theory how many classes are to be expected. There is no golden rule, LCA is a good method, but without theory it is quite meaningless. If you have little theory, what you can do to double check your findings is to relate your latent variable to a distal outcome (covariate) about which you might have some theory and see if it works out. For example, you suspect that one of your latent classes will be dominated by one gender: associate your latent variable with gender and see.
3. Parsimony rule: simple models are preferred to complex ones (Collins & Lanza, 2010). If a simpler model does all the work, why choose a complex one?

In your case, I would start with a 3 class model, since it is suggested by BIC and parsimony. After finishing the analysis and interpreting the findings, I would re-run the model with 4/5 classes and see if I would reach substantially different findings - something that is worth reporting on, any important or contradicting findings to what I have found with a 3 class model. If it just adds complexity, but does not contradict or improve what I have already known, I'd stick to a 3 class model.

Looking at the results, I think that the 5 class model does not provide anything beyond the 3 classes. In the 3 class model, you have one class of extensive drug users (16%), moderate drug users dominated by cannabis, popper, hallucinogens and cocaine (40%), and finally a class of light users dominated by alcohol and cannabis (44%). The 5 class model split the first two groups into specific smaller sub-groups, but you have to decide whether these splits are important for your research - whether they make sense for your research question.

I would also recommend checking bivariate residuals. It is possible that the model misfit that is suggesting more classes is generated by a residual association between your indicators. If you can justify it theoretically (for example by finding some similarity between the indicators beyond the latent class), you can add the residual association and obtain a similarly good fit with the 3 class model.

One last point, avoid using AIC for LCA altogether - it is a very poorly performing index! Use cAIC, BIC and aBIC instead. AIC does not correct for the sample size, which can be quite problematic with larger samples.

**Sources**:

Collins, L. M., & Lanza, S. T. (2010). Latent class and latent transition analysis: With applications in the social, behavioral, and health sciences. New York: Wiley.